# Why always true conditional type in return does not type check in this case

Tags: typescript

I find

```js
type B = { 
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
};

function get<F extends B, K extends keyof B>(f: F, k: K): F[K] {
  return f[k];
}
```

intuitively identical to

```js
function get<F extends B, K extends keyof B>(f: F, k: K): F extends B ? F[K] : undefined {
  return f[k];
}
```

but the latter does not type check:

```
Type 'F[K]' is not assignable to type 'F extends B ? F[K] : undefined'.
  Type 'F["foo"] | F["bar"]' is not assignable to type 'F extends B ? F[K] : undefined'.
    Type 'F["foo"]' is not assignable to type 'F extends B ? F[K] : undefined'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'F extends B ? F[K] : undefined'.
```

Hence a question: what does TS compiler know about types that is not obvious to me?

Playground: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAQlC8UDeUBQUoDMD22BcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYDc6UARgIYkEUCuAtgxCXQL51M7CgGNgZbBShUIwADwAxKBAAewCBQAmhWABooAaRXrNOqAGsIIbJlgA+ABSYCigxYKGAlK5MbtunAA-FCKANqGALpQBCJaEJiUEFrI9CRy7CTSmGEWkQKoQA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more like you know more than it does... the compiler doesn't try to do any deep analysis of conditional types that depend on unresolved generic type parameters.  That is, the conditional type `F extends B ? F[K] : undefined` isn't really evaluated inside the function implementation, where `F` has yet to be specified with a concrete type.  So while it's easy enough for you to see that `F extends B ? F[K] : undefined` must be the same as `F[K]`, because the condition `F extends B` is the same as the generic constraint `F extends B`, the compiler doesn't even begin to do this (likely for performance reasons).